# Method parameters, protocol methods, delegates and respondsToSelector calls

Tags: objective-c, delegates, protocols, respondstoselector

I have this kind of code :

**MyClass.h**

```
#import "MyOtherClass.h"

@interface MyClass : NSObject<SomeProtocol, MyOtherClassDelegate> {
...
}
```

**MyClass.m**

```
+ (void) doThis {
   [someObject doThisWithDelegate:self];  // someObject is MyOtherClass type
}
```

**MyOtherClass.h :**

```
@protocol MyOtherClassDelegate <NSObject>
@required
// Some methods
@end

- (void) doThisWithDelegate:(id<SomeOtherProtocol>)delegate;
```

**MyOtherClass.m :**

```
- (void) doThisWithDelegate:(id<SomeOtherProtocol>)delegate {
    if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(myProtocolMethod:error:)]) do things;
}
```

Doing like this, I have the following **warnings at compile time** :

on the line `[someObject doThisWithDelegate:self];`

```
"Incompatible pointer types sending Class to parameter of type id<SomeOtherProtocol>"
```

on the method declaratéin in MyOtherClass.h :

```
"Passing argument to parameter 'delegate' here"
```

Before, I hadn't typed the id param (with `id<SomeOtherProtocol>`), it was just "alone" (`id`). I noticed that the test :

```
if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(myProtocolMethod:error:)])
```

**returned FALSE** (but of course methods are implemented and declared in the delegate).

So I decided to try to force the `id` type to conform protocol that causes me that warning at compile time.

What is happening here ?
Why do I have this error, and why do the `respondsToSelector` do not return TRUE ?

Comment: If the call to `-respondsToSelector:` return FALSE and you believe the object actually implements the selector, then you're mistaken somewhere. Perhaps `self.delegate` isn't the object you thought it was. Maybe it's `nil`. Try logging it. Perhaps you've misspelled the method name in one of the places. In general, `-respondsToSelector:` doesn't care about the declared or actual type of the receiver, it's only testing whether it actually responds, so all the stuff about protocols and type declarations is irrelevant.

Comment: @KenThomases:the object is not nil, it is the good one (debugged), the names are ok, ... I don't see what can be wrong there

Comment: @KenThomases:I've suppressed the 'self.' reference from my code extract to simplify the problem, first because the problem is a compile problem that do not seems to be lined with that.$"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that I've declare the `doThis` method as a class method and not instance method. So `self` is not valid when passed as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call `respondsToSelector:` on a property with a type of `id<SomeProtocol>` then make sure your protocol conforms to the `NSObject` protocol.

Example:

```
@protocol SomeOtherProtocol <NSObject>
// methods
@end
```

This will then allow you to do:

```
if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(myProtocolMethod:error:)]) {
}
```

This assumes `delegate` is defined as:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<SomeOtherProtocol> delegate;
```

Comment: Why having the delegate declare with @property (nonatomic, weak) id delegate; would prevent respondsToSelector to work ?

Answer (score 1):

First make sure you conform to , respondsToSelector is part of NSObject.

Second I would check that i had effectively set the delegate property.

This line :

```
if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(myProtocolMethod:error:)])
```

should work, since the property delegate is pointing to an object that should have myProtocolMethod:error: ....

I would probably debug with a breakpoint or a test on a setter for the delegate :

```
-(void)setDelegate:(id)delegate 
{
NSLog("We are setting a delegate!: %@", [delegate description]);
 _delegate = delegate;
}
```

If when you run your app, you see the "We setting...." after you do your if line or if you don't see it at all, then you know where your issue is.

Comment: Yes, the delegate is set, protocol and delegate have the good references to NSObject, it's the good delegate that is set, it implements the tested method and that method is also decared. I don't see what is wrong...

Comment: Can I see your method declaration. It might be something related to that. As i had said, your code should work. I do that kind of check's all the time on @optional protocol methods.

Comment: Also make sure that you are conforming your "delegate" to your protocol (I guess you are... But...)  by adding <yourprotocol> on the .h class declattion.